# Creating a diagonal matrix

Tags: loops, matrix, stata

This is the code I currently have:

```
forv i = 1/10 {
    set obs 10
    gen x`i' = (_n-1)*10+`i'
}
```

How can I make it into a diagonal matrix so that entries are `0` whenever row ad column indexes are not equal?

This is the code I tried but did not work:

```
forv i=1/10 {
    set obs 10
    gen x`i' = (_n-1)*10+`i'

    foreach j of varlist x1-x10 {
        if _n ~= "`i'"
        replace `j' = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code block is legal (assuming no more than `10` observations in memory) but doesn't produce any thing close to a diagonal matrix. The command `set obs 10` should be executed once before the loop, not every time around the loop.

There are several errors in your inner loop in your second code block, but I won't spell them out. You're guessing wildly, not the way to write code!

You can get a diagonal matrix directly in Stata like this:

```
. matrix whatever = 7 * I(5)

. matrix list whatever

symmetric whatever[5,5]
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
r1   7
r2   0   7
r3   0   0   7
r4   0   0   0   7
r5   0   0   0   0   7
```

If you have reason to hold that as variables, then use `svmat`. You could create such a matrix as values of several variables in a loop, but it would be somewhat perverse:

```
clear

set obs 5

forvalues j = 1/5 {
    generate x`j' = 7 * (_n == `j')
}

list

     +------------------------+
     | x1   x2   x3   x4   x5 |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  7    0    0    0    0 |
  2. |  0    7    0    0    0 |
  3. |  0    0    7    0    0 |
  4. |  0    0    0    7    0 |
  5. |  0    0    0    0    7 |
     +------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @NickCox is also applicable in `mata` - Stata's matrix programming language:

```
. mata: A = 7 * I(5)

. mata: A
[symmetric]
       1   2   3   4   5
    +---------------------+
  1 |  7                  |
  2 |  0   7              |
  3 |  0   0   7          |
  4 |  0   0   0   7      |
  5 |  0   0   0   0   7  |
    +---------------------+
```

One can then get the matrix as variables with the `getmata` command:

```
. getmata (A*) = A

. list A*

     +------------------------+
     | A1   A2   A3   A4   A5 |
     |------------------------|
  1. |  7    0    0    0    0 |
  2. |  0    7    0    0    0 |
  3. |  0    0    7    0    0 |
  4. |  0    0    0    7    0 |
  5. |  0    0    0    0    7 |
     +------------------------+
```